# nopcommerce upgrade to 3.8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I have recently upgraded to 3.8 and now i'm faced with the following error :-

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.web.webPages.razor/host: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

apparently the issue is with the following line :-

```
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```

how ever, this line doesn't actually exist in the config file.

I've Googled and Googled, and still cannot resolve the issue.

The site is installed on server 2008

any advice on this?

Comment: Did to try with `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Reinstall`

Comment: @Div i didnt use the source release, just the packaged release...  do i need to get the source release?

Comment: OK, could you explain me how did you upgrade?

Comment: @div i followed the instructions from text file.  I ran the upgrade script against the database, I then copied the 2 settings text files out of the current site. I then deleted the site, and replaced it with the downloaded site. The 2 setting files where then copied back into app_data folder.

Comment: Okay, can you paste full error to the question. May its because, some were modification remaining.

Comment: Which version did you upgrade from?